# Face recognition with eye, mouth, ears.. in Javascript

Tags: javascript, canvas

I was wondering and searching for information about face recognition using Canvas, and specifically how to detect the parts of a face.

Let's say I take a picture from my webcam, and then I want to detect the eyes, mouth, nose and ears to split them into different images.

What would be the process for doing this ?

Comment: what have to find in your research? Can you do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Any library for face recognition in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7291065/any-library-for-face-recognition-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use HTML5's [getUserMedia](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/) and also [headtrackr.js](https://github.com/auduno/headtrackr/) to achieve what you are looking for. Also, then you can detect objects, get access to user media and many more things.
Hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: I saw this lib, but I would need to detect the individual objects such as the eyes, mouth, ears...

Comment: Then i guess you should look at [this link](http://www.smartjava.org/content/face-detection-using-html5-javascript-webrtc-websockets-jetty-and-javacvopencv), where it is explained for detecting eyes, ears etc separately.

Answer (score 6):

What i did recently trying to solve same problem (face and eyes detection) was:

1. Scale down processed image to achieve decent performance (I downscaled everything to 320px width)
2. Detect face in image using Core Computer Vision Library - https://github.com/liuliu/ccv
3. Based on the detected face rectangle information detect eyes using HAAR object detector (it has cascade for eyes only detection - https://github.com/inspirit/jsfeat

For step 2 i also used "grayscale" and "equalize_histogram" from JSFEAT library.

Also if step 3 fails you can try to guess eyes position (depends on how high accuracy you're going for).

This workflow gave me satisfying results and performance. It tested it both on desktop (~500ms on iMac) and mobile devices (~3000ms on iphone 4 using image from webcam).
Unfortunately I cannot post a link to working example at this point, but i'll post a link to github once i have something there.